# Change animation theme when system theme is changing in UWP using Lottie

Tags: uwp, lottie, windows-themes

I have a .gif icon which I am trying to set using Lottie in UWP. The icon has two versions for light and dark mode respectively. But I cant change the icon when application theme is changed. I have followed this way,

1. Created a theme dictionary using this,

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                   xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
                   xmlns:lottie="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie">
   <ResourceDictionary>    
       <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
           <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <Style x:Key="AnimationStyle" TargetType="lottie:LottieVisualSource">
                   <Setter Property="UriSource" Value="/Assets/Icons/theme-light/lottie_animation.json" />
                </Style>
           </ResourceDictionary>
           <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
              <Style x:Key="AnimationStyle" TargetType="lottie:LottieVisualSource">
                  <Setter Property="UriSource" Value="/Assets/Icons/theme-dark/lottie_animation.json" />
              </Style>
           </ResourceDictionary>
   </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```
2. After that I have called it following this,

```
    <Grid.Row="3">
        <muxc:AnimatedVisualPlayer HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Stretch="Uniform">
            <lottie:LottieVisualSource UriSource="{ThemeResource AnimationStyle}"/>
        </muxc:AnimatedVisualPlayer>
    </Grid>
```

But it does not show in both theme (Dark and Light). Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you could just save the string value for the `UriSource`. Then I tested this, the result shows that the `LottieVisualSource` will not use the updated source when the Theme is changed.
So we need to use the [Theme Listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/themelistener) to detect the theme change and manually update the `UriSource`.

Here is the code that I'm using for testing.

```
 <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
        <x:String x:Key="AnimationStyle">ms-appx:///Assets/Icon/Theme-Light/First.json</x:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
        <x:String x:Key="AnimationStyle">ms-appx:///Assets/Icon/Theme-Dark/Second.json</x:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="HighContrast">
        
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

**MainPage.Xaml**

```
    <Page.Resources>
    <!--for a simple test, add the dictionary in the page resource-->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="re.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{ThemeResource AnimationStyle}"/>

    <muxc:AnimatedVisualPlayer Grid.Row="1" x:Name="LottiePlayer" AutoPlay="True" >
        <lottie:LottieVisualSource x:Name="LottieJsonSource" Options="All" UriSource="{ThemeResource AnimationStyle}"/>
    </muxc:AnimatedVisualPlayer>
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.Xaml.cs**

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var Listener = new ThemeListener();
        Listener.ThemeChanged += Listener_ThemeChanged;
    }

    private void Listener_ThemeChanged(ThemeListener sender)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ThemeChanged");
        //update the source manually. The AnimationStyle is actually changed when the theme is changed
        //but the LottieJsonSource is still using the old cache.
        LottieJsonSource.UriSource = new Uri((string)this.Resources["AnimationStyle"]); ;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @RoyLi-MSFT for your valuable suggestion. I have finally able to change the theme following your suggestion.

Comment: Hello @RoyLi-MSFT I have another followup question, what if I want to do same thing using codegen instead of Lottie?